# In Python's Turtle, how can I pause my program while waiting for a click event?

Tags: python, python-3.x, onclick, turtle-graphics

Working with Python's turtle graphics, and I want to accept I user click. However, I also need my program to pause while waiting for the click instead of continuing through like it does currently. Here's my setup:

```
from turtle import *
screen = getscreen()

def getInput():
    coordinates = onscreenclick(clickHandler) # Returns x and y coordinates as a list
    print(coordinates) # Prints "None" as coordinates is empty
```

So how can I setup a pause so `print(coordinates)` is only ran after a click is received?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below should do what you want.

The last statement in a turtle program turns control over to the event loop which waits for clicks and other events -- typically that statement is one of `mainloop()`, `done()`, or `exitonclick()` (not applicable in this situation):

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

FONT = ("Arial", 18, "normal")

def clickHandler(x, y):
    yertle.undo()  # unwrite previous coordinates
    yertle.write((x, y), align="center", font=FONT)

yertle = Turtle(visible=False)

yertle.write((0, 0), align="center", font=FONT)

screen = Screen()

screen.onscreenclick(clickHandler)

screen.mainloop()
```

Rather than print coordinates to the console, I've made it write them to the window itself.